# funny Code behaviour

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I am trying to connect to a mysql database with the following code in my `main()` function.

```
MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
```

which works fine and I get a pointer value returned.

I have created another c++ file with a function in it as below

```
int Newl_connection(FileHandler& pProcLog)
{
    MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

compiling and Linking fine, I have made several calls to the same line of code  in the main function (as a test) and all ok but when I run the code it fails at the line in the Newl_connection() function.

I have stripped the Newl_connection to as basic as possible, and included all the headers from the file containing Main() into the file containing Newl_connection() function.

THe compiler error I recieve is

> Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>   0x00007ffff6bc6428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
>   54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
>
> Attempt to use a type name as an expression.
>
> Attempt to use a type name as an expression

Attempt to use a type name as an expression. appears for all instance calls, but the call in the `Newl_connection()` function is terminal.

I have tried removing all other instances in `main()` and still get the same problem.

Why should code work in one place but behave differently in another?
Help would be appreciated I am at my witts end on this one.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is due to incorrect including of headers?  But with out a minimal, complete example it is hard to tell.

Comment: When you call the function, do you pass it a valid `FileHandler` object?

Comment: _"Why should code work in one place but behave differently in another?"_ Many, many reasons. Present your [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

According to your function header:

```
int Newl_connection(FileHandler& pProcLog)
```

you should call it with a valid object of type `FileHandler`.
Setting the variable name as `pProcLog` makes me think you want to use it as a pointer to an object. Then the declaration should be:

```
int Newl_connection(FileHandler* pProcLog)
```

This way you could call the function safe with a `null` value as argument.

Comment: Will C++ let you compile a program with this type of mismatch?

Comment: The syntax is correct. Using & makes a **reference** to the object: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B) It is very similar to **pointer** but calling it is different.

Comment: I know what a reference is. But if the function is declared to take a reference, and you try calling it with a pointer, the compiler should report it as an error.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree, compiler will fail.

Comment: Hi guys thanks but the issue is not with the call to the function it is with the line in the function:- MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL); which works ok in main() function but not in the newl_Connection() function. I am passing a class in by reference(pProcLog), this part works OK throughout the wider application.

Comment: Further info on the problem as follows - removed the parameter from the function call newl_connection(), copied the function into the same file as main() and tried calling the function from both within main() and from another file within the application. Called from within main () = OK from outside main() the error occurs.

Comment: @John Roberts : Is your app multi-threaded? There is an issue about multi-threading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-init.html

Comment: Not that I am aware of, this is a C++ app relatively small in operational terms but over many c source files.